# Why did the BBC use "would have done" instead of Simple Past to describe this recent event?

Tags: past-tense, usage, idiomatic-language

The following sentence is about a problem that took place last week when an aircraft's door panel blew out while it was in the air.

> The aircraft was delivered to Alaska Airlines on 31 October 2023, and would only have completed around 100 flights a month.

[BBC - Questions about airplane door problem](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-67915771)

Why say **"...would only have completed..."** instead of **"....completed...."**? We are not making a guess about 2000 years ago, we are simply talking about something that happened last week, so why avoid the simple past?

This usage of **"...would have done..."** for a fact that took place last week is something that I can't easily understand as a non-native speaker. I think it is because this usage -though being so common- is not covered at schools as an alternative form of Simple past tense.

But I see it being used so commonly that it now gives me the feeling that **"would have done"** is more than a **Type 3 conditional** and it functions as another version of Simple past tense. The only difference seems to be *when you want to emphasize that you may not be 100% sure about a detail, a number, etc. of the past event.*

But, saying this would still not be clear enough for non-native speakers, because in almost every case there might be some details where one might not be 100% sure. If the sole reason of **not being 100% sure about a detail** would be the reason to switch to **"would have done"**, then how can we decide whether we should avoid **"simple past"** even telling about our daily lives, too, as there is always something where one may not be a 100% sure about a detail?

For example:

> What did you do last weekend?

So we say

> I got up at around 7. And at around 9, I left for a walk, and later I did that ..... so on.

(Normally, even if we may not be sure about the exact hours of what we did, we usually answer this question in simple past structure. And for the emphasis of uncertainty about numbers or any other details, we add something like **"around"** in the past tense. So, we do not feel any need for another structure like **"would have done".**)

However, considering such common usage of **"would have done"** by native-speakers, I ask myself why we don't use **"would have done"** at all when we,too, can't be 100% sure about numbers. And I also wonder how it would sound like if I answered to the question in a **"would have done"** structure instead of **"simple past"?**

> - Last weekend, I would have got up around 7 in the morning,*
> - Then I would have left for a walk at around 9,*
> - Later on, I would have gone for lunch around 13.00.*
> - Probably at 23.30, I would have gone to sleep.*

Would it not sound strange?

Comment: By my reading, “would have” means “was expected to”, using “would” as past tense of “will”; as in, this is the amount of usage that was planned for the aircraft. But I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: would have completed is **speculative**. The journalist is not 100% sure but is making an educated guess based on available information. Compare: the author actually knew the delivery date. That was not speculation.

Comment: People use would have + past participle all the time when they are unsure. Think of police procedurals when the person being questioned uses this type of construction as you have done in your example.

Comment: @Lambie, Thanks for the comment. So, when I, as a non-native speaker, am unsure about a past event, what I do is to make a Simple past sentence, and simply include a word that emphasizes my uncertainty. For instance, if I am not sure about last weekend times, I would say "I probably got up at 9 in the morning." or "I think I got up at 9 in the morning". So, have I been doing it wrong by not using "would have done" in such circumstances?

Comment: No, no, no. **What you say is FINE so is**: I would have got up at 9:00, when or if you are not sure. Compare that to the BBC article: they used a simple way to express a speculative idea in  writing. They could not have done what you did in speech. "probably completed 100 flights". Get it? :) This "would have past participle" usage is *more formal* and for writing.

Comment: @‍Lambie: There are multiple mistakes in your comment: "Fine **as** is" and "would have **gotten** up". Also, it's not primarily a matter of "formal" or "writing".

Comment: @user21820 There are no mistakes. X is fine. So is: [Y] *typos*. And fyi, "would have got up" is British get, got, got. They don't say gotten. "I probably got up at 9:00" versus "I would have got up at 9:00", would be in response to a question, very often. And in the question this applies to formal writing and is speculative. The BBC newswriters don't know how many flights exactly were completed.

Comment: Use of "would have" implies a lack of absolute certainty. It's pretty common to use it this way in English.  There's nothing strange about it at all.

Comment: Also "fine as is" is a common/informal way to say "It's fine as it is".. It's not a mistake.  Also Lambie is not wrong with his use of "gotten".  It's considered non-standard in standard Br.Eng now, but some of us do still use it here. It's use in the UK is regional. The Americans didn't just make it up. They got it from us Brits!!!

Comment: @‍Lambie: So there's missing punctuation (which is still a mistake). As for "gotten", alright I was unaware of regional dialects. But I still dispute that it is about formality or writing! The meaning doesn't change in speech, and "would have" can be used informally too. *the-baby-is-you*'s answer gets it right.

Comment: @user21820 It was a typo for pete's sake. And it's not the use of "would have"; it's **would have + a past participle**. The journalists use "would have completed" as non-hard fact. And it is formal. Otherwise, they would have written: probably completed x number of flights, which would sound bad here.

Comment: *would'only've* - they're saying that's a low number of flights to have a window blow out on. "why avoid the simple past" - IDK what that even means. That's just how people talk.

Comment: The BBC used "would only have" not "would have done".

Comment: It is not formal. I use it in speech and in informal contexts too. "probably" conveys a totally different meaning so obviously it can't be used. (There is no probability here.) Just because many native speakers do not speak proper English all the time doesn't imply that the proper phrasing is formal. In some regions, native speakers *write* "would of"; it doesn't make "would've" formal. Similarly here; "would only have completed ..." is not formal, regardless of how few people speak it. The distinction between formal and informal can only be accurately discerned by asking proficient speakers.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's not about lack of precision. It's about lack of direct evidence.

It's unclear where the article's author gets the "a few flights a month" figure, but we can surmise they didn't get it from anyone who actually counted all the flights before the failure; with such a new plane, most of the available data probably came from before it went into service. "Would have done" in this case means "That was the plan, and nothing changed as far as we know."

You don't have to speculate about what you *would have done* last week if you remember it yourself or have records of it. You use it to signal that you're deducing the information based on your usual routine.

> The 24th? Let's see, that was a Wednesday, so I would have had lunch at the diner. No wait, I remember now—I had leftover curry from my anniversary the night before. I ate it in my office and Tom came in around 12:15.

Comment: "If it is about lack of direct evidence.", then why does author say "The aircraft was delivered to Alaska Airlines on 31 October 2023". He does not have direct evidence whether it was delivered on that day or not. So, wasn't he supposed to say "The aircraft would have been delivered to Alaska Airlines on 31 October 2023".?

Comment: Also, unless we see something with our own eyes or hear, we can not have direct evidence on anything in the past. Same is true for authors. Most of the time, they didn't see the actual happening that they publish about. So, then they should always use "would have done" instead of "sipmle past", shouldn't they? Same is true for us. For example, if you see pieces of glass scattered on the street,  aren't we supposed to say "There would have been an accident."?

Comment: @yunus Not _firsthand_ evidence, but he presumably heard it stated as fact by someone else. There's no speculation involved, only trust in his sources.

Comment: @yunus As for the glass on the street, we say "there **must** have been an accident", which is both more certain and less certain depending on how you look at it. We have direct evidence that _something_ happened, but we're just guessing what it was. With "would have been", we're basically assuming _nothing_ atypical happened because we have no evidence against it, and describing what the typical scenario would be.

Comment: News reporting tends to be extremely careful. If they use the plain past for anything, it means that their evidence has met their own exacting standards. "Would have done" signals the reader that there is speculation occurring. Being able to distinguish between speculation and fact is an important element of media literacy.

Comment: @YonKuma, thanks for the comment. I understand your point that it results from being extremely careful about something which he can't know for sure. Then why does the same reporter use a simple past structure in the same sentence: "The aircraft was delivered to Alaska Airlines on 31 October 2023". Shouldn't he have said "The aircraft would have been delivered ........."?, because he must be careful about anything which he can't know for sure?

Comment: @yunus As stated, because the newspaper has met that standard of evidence. Someone who works at the newspaper has seen either a document attesting that the aircraft was delivered on that day or a trustworthy newspaper article reporting on the delivery of the airplane, or has talked directly to someone with knowledge of the delivery.

Comment: @yunus I think the "extremely careful about something he can't know for sure" is tripping you up. In the philosophical sense, there are not very many things that we can know with 100% certainty. However, the author clearly has some kind of hard data indicating when the plane was delivered. I'm sure the author wasn't present when it was delivered, but perhaps the delivery is a public record or something. However, the "100 flights per month" figure is likely an average or an approximation. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Tashus, yes that is right. You understood what trips me up. And what I understand from your comment, this structure is more about formal writing (reports, statements etc) and it is not one which can replace "Simple past" in daily life, based on the idea that we can't prove something while telling about something that happened in the past in daily life. Do you think so?

Comment: It's not about formality, it's about the requirement to express uncertainty. You rarely need to express uncertainty about events that you lived; though the answer gives an excellent example of when you may need to. Newspapers routinely need to distinguish between "certainties" (as governed by their own evidentiary requirements) and likely speculation.

Comment: You can be sure of one thing (delivery date of aircraft) and unsure (speculative use) of another: would have done.

Comment: @yunus You could use this in daily life. Let's say you have a morning routine that includes brushing your teeth, but it is such a habit that you don't really think about it. Someone might ask you, "Did you brush your teeth?" and even if you don't remember with certainty, you could say, "I would have brushed them this morning."

Comment: @the-baby-is-you, _"With "would have been", we're basically assuming nothing atypical happened because we have no evidence against it, and describing what the typical scenario would be"_. I don't quite understand your sentence. Could you please elaborate what "atypical", "against it" (against what), and "typical" mean in the context of your statement?

Comment: @Sergey "Typical" - what happens in the majority of cases. "Atypical" - not typical; something unusual has occurred. "Against it" - against the assumption that this specific case was typical, with "it" meaning "this case being typical". To paraphrase, "We know of nothing unusual that happened, so we will describe what usually happens."

Comment: @YonKuma, You essentially provided the definitions of these words. I know and understand the definitions. What I don't understand is what exactly the author meant in the context of his statement.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you, Still, I would like to hear an answer from you as the author of the statement, what do you mean by the words "atypical", "against it" and "typical", with examples for each word please.
For example, I don't understand whether an "accident" is typical or atypical in the context of your statement or an "accident" doesn’t fit here at all. And I would like to hear more examples of what is typical and what is atypical in the context of your statement.

Answer (score 14):

All modals have an *epistemic* reading (about the speaker's knowledge) as well as a *deontic* reading (about necessity, possibility, probability, in the real world).

In English, when modals are used with "have", but not following a conditional clause ("if" etc) they are very often epistemic.

Here, as others have said *would have* indicates that the speaker does not know the number, but has deduced or concluded it from other information.

Comment: Exactly. People don't understand that *It would have seen 100 flights* is merely the past tense of *It will have seen 100 flights*, both completely epistemic. They mean that the speaker is certain about something that happened in the past, just one version backshifted from the other.

Comment: @tchrist, _**un**certain_?

Comment: It is not "would have". It's: **would have + past participle**. But I don't see  how this even really addresses the problem in a learner's terms. This is not the past tense of will here.

Answer (score 5):

The problem that grounded the plane happened on January 5. It didn't **complete** around 100 flights a month, since its service was cut short by the accident. It **would have completed** around that number of flights, if it had continued flying as usual.

Additionally, since it was in service for such a short time (two full months of November and December) the difference is significant, meaning the plane flew roughly 220 flights instead of 300, which it would have completed without the issues.

If the plane had been in service for several years, they could have said "completed around 100 flights a month", since the one, short month would not have changed the average meaningfully.

Finally, it is possible that the plane did not reach full service yet, but the plan was that it eventually would fly around that number of flights a month. Flightradar shows that it had completed only 145 flights after being delivered.

Comment: So, contrary to all others, you think that this is a Conditional Type 3 sentence?

Comment: It lacks the 'if' that would make it conditional. I agree with the other answers grammatically, but disagree that the structure points to lack of evidence. Rather it would not be factually correct to say 'completed 100 flights a month' as it had not happened yet!

Comment: It is similar to conditional type 3, since it seems what is implied is "The aircraft was delivered to Alaska Airlines on 31 October 2023, [and if the plane had continued flying,] it would only have completed around 100 flights a month".

Comment: I'm sure the journalist simply intended to "hedge" his assertion about how many flights the plane made ***before*** the failure. He wasn't talking about how many flights it ***would have made / would be making** in the future* once it gets put back into service (which *will* happen; they wouldn't write off a whole plane just because of one fault, not matter how bad that fault).

Comment: I really don't understand the other comments about estimates and such. "Would have" means as @SakariCajanus stated - "would have ... but didn't". The OP's question, "the plane would have completed 100 flights, EXCEPT the door blew off and now it won't."  "I would have gone on a walk, but its raining and I might melt." As for the exact meaning of the statement given by the OP - I have no idea what they were trying to say; if a door blows off an aircraft, the concern is who went with it, not how many flights it would have made - terrible journalism trying to up the word count.

Comment: @user3481644 The relevance is how we know they meant it as an estimate, not as a reference to potential missed flights in the future. How could the number of flights possibly be relevant to a story about an airplane that had a part fail? Well, if the airplane was old and had been used a lot then we might think the failure was due to wear-and-tear or maintenance. But the author clarifies for us that the plane was quite new and hadn't flown many times at all. The author provides an estimate rather than looking up flight records and specifically counting because that's all we need.

Comment: @user3481644 _"if a door blows off an aircraft, the concern is who went with it, not how many flights it would have made"_ I don't quite understand your point. The question in the article whose answer starts with that sentence is _"Why did a brand-new aircraft experience such a dramatic technical failure?"_ A person asking that question does not care if Mr. Smith or Mrs. Doe went with the door, otherwise they would ask about that. But the person probably is very interested in what kind of a plane it was and how much it was used and whether that can be an explanation of why the front fell off.

Comment: Another example: I would have done my homework, but the dog ate it!

Answer (score 3):

1. The **would have** implies that it's an estimate or a guess of what the actual number is.
2. It can also be used to imply that the number can only be estimated because it's no longer possible to measure it. For example, if the plane had crashed and couldn't be flown anymore, the same sentence would imply that the estimate is because it can no longer be measured (because the plane is destroyed).

Answer (score 0):

The article contains the following statement.

> The aircraft was delivered to Alaska Airlines on 31 October 2023, and
> would only have completed around 100 flights a month. Normal wear and
> tear or maintenance failures are unlikely to have been factors
> affecting such a young aircraft.

The meaning of this statement is as follows.

> The aircraft was only recently delivered and the plan was to complete only
> around 100 flights a month. How did it happen that a brand-new
> aircraft with not that big number of flights a month experienced such
> a dramatic technical failure? You know, normal wear and tear or
> maintenance failures are unlikely to have been factors affecting such
> a young aircraft.

No, "would have done" does not function as another version of Simple past tense with the only difference when you want to emphasize that you may not be 100% sure about a detail of the past event.

"Would have done" is not about uncertainty in details at all.
"Would have done" is about what the plan was or how things usually happen.

The author is certain that the plan was to complete around 100 flights a month and he has no doubt about the number: it is around 100 flights a month.

The author said "...would only have completed..." instead of "....completed...." because 100 flights a month have not yet been completed. There was a plan to complete only 100 flights a month and that plan was abrupted due to the failure, so he said "...would only have completed around 100 flights a month."

You also wondered how it would sound like if you answered to the question "What did you do last weekend?" in the "would have done" structure instead of "simple past"?

> Last weekend, I would have got up around 7 in the morning. Then I
> would have left for a walk at around 9. Later on, I would have gone
> for lunch around 13.00. Probably at 23.30, I would have gone to sleep.

OK, It could sound like this:

> Last weekend, I had a plan to get up around 7 in the morning. (But I
> got up only at 12:00, because the day before I worked hard and late.)
> Then I had a plan to leave for a walk at around 9. (But I didn’t go
> because I slept until 12:00) Later on, I had a plan to go for lunch
> around 13.00. (But I didn’t have lunch, because at 13:00 I had just
> had breakfast) Finally, I had a plan to go to sleep around 23.30. (But
> in fact, I went to bed at 21:00 because at that time I was already
> really sleepy.)

And here you are certain about the numbers.

Please note that the "would have done" structure here does not mean you are not being 100% sure about a detail. It wouldn't sound like this:

> Last weekend, I got up around 7 in the morning or maybe around 6 in
> the morning or maybe around 8 in the morning, I'm not sure. Then I
> left for a walk at around 9 or maybe at around 10 or maybe at around
> 11, I'm not sure. Later on, I gone for a lunch around 13.00 or maybe
> at around 13:30 or maybe at around 14, I'm not sure. Probably at 23.30
> or maybe at 23:00 or maybe at 22:00, I'm not sure, I gone to sleep.

If the question were "What do you usually do on weekends?" and should you answered to the question in the "would have done" structure:

> On weekends, I would have got up around 7 in the morning. Then I would
> have left for a walk at around 9. Later on, I would have gone for
> lunch around 13.00. Probably at 23.30, I would have gone to sleep.

It would sound like this:

> On weekends, I usually get up around 7 in the morning. Then I usually
> leave for a walk at around 9. Later on, I usually go for lunch around
> 13.00. Probably at 23.30, I usually go to sleep.

Again, here you are confident in the numbers.

Comment: @Sergey, Thanks for the detailed answer, I agree mostly, but I still have a question. You say "...100 flights a month have not yet been completed a month..... ", however, it was actually completed for 2 months. 100 flights were completed in November and another 100 flights were completed in December. This is what the plan was. So the plan was implemented. So unlike what you say, the structure "would have completed" doesn't apply to November and December, because what was planned actually was implemented. The structure "would have done" only applies to January.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Done.

Comment: @yunus, I think the author have written "The aircraft... would only have completed around 100 flights a month" to emphasize that there was a plan to fly only around 100 flights a month, but even that modest plan was interrupted. Because at the time of writing the aircraft was grounded and undergoing investigation because of the accident.

Answer (score -1):

Its a slightly odd bit of Grammar - the Past habitual
There's a wiki page about this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_markers_of_habitual_aspect

It is mentioned on the British council page for learners of English
"Would for past habits is slightly more formal than used to. It is often used in stories."

Native speakers of english probably wouldn't even know they were doing this.

A quick google finds Tony Bennet telling us:
"My father would go to the top of the mountains in Calabria, Italy to sing and the whole village could hear him"

As it is recounting something that might have happened regularly, its perhaps not that accurate, even if you said "On friday night we would drink 6 pints".

Note that in many cases you can replace "would" with "used to".

Of course in this case, it looks slightly different because it changes the tense to "have done", but the examples would have a similar meaning with "have gone" and "have drunk".

Comment: This is an interesting usage, but I don't think it matches the example - as the lede of the Wikipedia article says, the habitual aspect is about _repetition_ or _continuous existence_. This appears instead to be a marker of ["evidentiality" or "epistemic modality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidentiality#In_English_(not_grammaticalized))